# Getting SQLEXCEPTION message in MySQL procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can I get error text in MySQL stored procedure when SQLEXCEPTION occurs?

I need something like this:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION    
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO my_log (error_message) 
    VALUES (SQLEXCEPTION.message);
END;
```

Comment: Which version of MySql are you using?

Comment: http://marcalff.blogspot.com/2011/10/mysql-get-diagnostics.html

Comment: 5.1.49
I found that not long ago was added new feature GET DIAGNOSTICS, that solves my problem.

Comment: But it is added to 5.6.4... anyway thanks for the answer!

Comment: GET DIAGNOSTICS is available from 5.6.4. Is there another way for lower version,.?

Answer (score 9):

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION    
BEGIN

 GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
    @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;

    INSERT INTO my_log (error_message) 
    SELECT @p2;
END;
```