# Getting SQLEXCEPTION message in procedures MySQL 5.5.x

Tags: mysql, exception, sqlexception

How can I get error text in **MySQL 5.5** stored procedure when `SQLEXCEPTION` occurs?

I need something along these lines to see what went wrong:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION    
BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
    SELECT "Table @p5 (Msg State @p2): @p1"
END;
```

Similar to [Getting SQLEXCEPTION message in MySQL procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7873266/153923), but there the Version was 5.6.4 - so **GET DIAGNOSTICS** was available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I know, there is no way to emulate or replace the functionality of `GET DIAGNOSTICS` in lower versions of MySQL (lower than 5.6.4).

There are many entries on [bugs.mysql.com](http://bugs.mysql.com/) and on MySQL forums which asks this feature. (Lke this one: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11660)

I do not know that you can or can not upgrade your MySQL instance, but as I know, this is your only chance.

I found (possibly you found them too) some questions related to this one, but all of them are either talking about version 5.6.4 or there are no answers:

- [How to get exception message on stored procedure in MySQL 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298391/how-to-get-exception-message-on-stored-procedure-in-mysql-5-5)
- [Getting SQLEXCEPTION message in MySQL procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873266/getting-sqlexception-message-in-mysql-procedures)

**EDIT**

If you can, handle the MySQL errors in the client application.

You can list the errors and warnings with `SHOW ERRORS` and `SHOW WARNINGS` statements outside of the `HANDLER`s, but you can not insert the result of those statements into a table. Inside the handler, those statements will give empty resultset.

For specific states, you can declare individual handlers. This way, you could know the state, but you do not know any other details.

Check out this article: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-error-handling-in-stored-procedures/

Comment: Is there any way to get/report information out of the exception that is caught?

Comment: I do not know any. If you  write your handler for a specific state, you will know the state. But there are too many states to write a handler for each one.

Comment: Check this article: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-error-handling-in-stored-procedures/