# Retrieving error for failed event

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to find out what happen if an event failed, this is my event sql:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `cdr2015_daily_update`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
DO 
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR MYSQLEXCEPTION, MYSQLWARNING
    BEGIN
    insert into events_state values ('cdr2015_daily_update', 'true', now(), 'unknown', 'unknown')
    END;

    insert into 
        cdr2015_v2 (clid, src, dst, dcontext, channel, dstchannel) 
    select 
        calldate, clid, src, dst, dcontext, channel, dstchannel
        from cdr where DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%Y-%m-%d') = subdate(current_date, 1); -- yesterday calls 
        
END; $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Every day at 03:00 does an backup of the calls the day before. This event will fail for sure, but I'd like to know the error, something like:

```
`Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` , is it possible to catch this error and insert it into another table?
```

This is the events_state table:

```
CREATE TABLE `events_state` (
`event` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`failed` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`fail_date` datetime,
`reason1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`reason2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`RID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`RID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Now event is inserting this:

```
insert into events_state values ('cdr2015_daily_update', 'true', now(), 'unknown', 'unknown')
```

Can it be changed to something like this?

```
insert into events_state values ('cdr2015_daily_update', 'true', now(), MYSQLEXCEPTION, MYSQLWARNING)
```

Also I couldn't manage to run this event since I'm getting error on both `END;`, here are some screenshots from mysql-workbench:

[image: Test]
[image: Test2]

**Update:** Tried changing second `END` from `END; $$` to `END;` , workbench wont display any error but it wont run the query either.

**Update 2:** Changed line `insert ... 'unknown')` to `insert ... 'unknown');` , added `;` at end of line. The query now runs, but im getting another error: `Error Code: 1319. Undefined CONDITION: EXCEPTION`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct query:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `cdr2015_daily_update`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
DO 
BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
    insert into events_state values ('cdr2015_daily_update', 'true', now(), 'unknown', 'unknown', 0);
    END;

    insert into 
        cdr2015 (calldate, clid, src, dst, dcontext, channel, dstchannel) 
    select 
        calldate, clid, src, dst, dcontext, channel, dstchannel
        from cdr where DATE_FORMAT(calldate, '%Y-%m-%d') = subdate(current_date, 1)
        limit 10;

END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

My MySQL version is 5.1 so the error handling wont be possible. "Inserting" the error text from an exception is only possible from version 5.6 on, references:

[Getting SQLEXCEPTION message in procedures MySQL 5.5.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045081/getting-sqlexception-message-in-procedures-mysql-5-5-x)

[MySQL Stored Procedure Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764887/mysql-stored-procedure-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

About the error in the END, is only

```
> Your code
> ; //this ; is used to close the insert i think
> END $$
> DELIMITER ;
```

(*do not put **';'***), try that, it should work now

Comment: tried END $$ and doesnt work neither, tried END; without $$ and query wont run

Comment: Whats the error message you got when you only put END $$ ? You are also putting the DELIMITER ; above that right?, i'll edit shortly my answer

Comment: Ok, i think you are missing a semincolor before END, tried my edited answer now

Comment: Does my answer help you? As for your second update, you want to put Mysqlexception as the result or as string? i mean, you can put 
**insert into events_state values ('cdr2015_daily_update', 'true', now(), 'MYSQLEXCEPTION',' MYSQLWARNING')** and it will appear but as string. Reply back when you have tested

Comment: tried a few things but not that, gona update soon in half hour or so, ill keep on with the tests

Comment: posted the answer :) ... topic closed for me, since that mysql is in production and i cant update it, its gona die like that.