# Event with cursor not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert a record into one table based on the select query result.

When I am executing a query that time I clearly able to see that record should need to insert into a table as am expecting.

But somehow it's not inserted a record So would like to know, What I miss to add

Snippet Code :

```
CREATE EVENT event_1 ON SCHEDULE  EVERY 60 SECOND DO 
                            BEGIN
                            DECLARE lc_current_time DATETIME;
                            DECLARE unuse_count INT;
                            DECLARE assign TINYINT;
                            DECLARE total_sum INT;
                            DECLARE check_count INT;
                            DECLARE select_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT count(id) as count,A.assign, B.sum, truncate(B.sum*100.00/100,0) as check_count FROM table1 A INNER JOIN (Select assign, count(id) sum from table1 where cli_group_id = 5 Group by assign) B on A.assign = B.assign WHERE cli_group_id = 5 and field1 ='' Group by field1, A.assign;
                            SET lc_current_time = CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '+0:00');
                            OPEN select_cursor;
                            LOOP 
                            FETCH select_cursor INTO unuse_count,assign,total_sum,check_count;
                            IF unuse_count <= check_count THEN
                                insert into report(triggered_date,alert_id,alert_name,type,status,email,trunk_cli_id,triggered_value,threshold_value) values (lc_current_time,19,'CLI',4,1,'abc@test.com',5,check_count,unuse_count);
                            END IF;
                            END LOOP;
                            CLOSE select_cursor;
                            END
```

Output of select query :

```
+-------+-------------+-----+-------------+
| count | assign      | sum | check_count |
+-------+-------------+-----+-------------+
|     8 |           0 |  11 |          11 |
|     2 |           1 |   3 |           3 |
+-------+-------------+-----+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Problem :

Here from output we can clearly see that `count < check_count`  so record should have to insert an entry into report table.

Comment: number of parameters in the insert query (9)  not equal the number of values you are inserting (8) that's why the insert query is probably failing

Comment: @YosraHamza: I didnt notice that one. i think it must be that reason.

Comment: @YosraHamza : Have tried after insert record as well as manual check but still its not working.

Comment: Did you try to see if any errors was logged by mysql during execution, this might help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764887/mysql-stored-procedure-error-handling
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045081/getting-sqlexception-message-in-procedures-mysql-5-5-x